# input of character in c

Tags: c, char, scanf

i am trying to read input character until it is 'a'.however i need all the characters typed until a.the problem is it is also taking new line as a character.that is when i press a character(say f) an enter it is taking f as well as new line char in the next loop.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char val;
    while(1)
    {
        printf("\nenter val: (a to stop)");
        scanf("%c",&val);
        printf("val is %d\n",(int)val);
        if(val=='a')
            break;
        else
            continue;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
enter val: (a to stop)f
val is 102

enter val: (a to stop)val is 10

enter val: (a to stop)
```

Comment: Tip: Stop using `scanf` and start using things like `fread` or `fgetc`.

Comment: It's not clear what your question is. Newline *is* a character, so the behaviour you see is certainly expected. What is it exactly that you would want?

Comment: `else continue` is unneeded

Comment: @moonshines: No, the newline character is always a character. It is usually possible to configure your input device so that the input is returned as soon as a character is pressed rather than waiting for a newline character, but the details as to how you do that depend on your operating system. There are many SO questions which deal with that topic.

Comment: @rici i need the values entered until 'a' is entered so giving char and pressing enter unneccessarily adds new line character so how to do that without new line character.i.e

Comment: @rici is there anyway i tell the program my input is over other than the new line char as it is interferes with my program.

Comment: scanf("%c",&dummy); adding this after scanning value solves it the dummy just gets the newline however it looks very unproffesional.

Comment: moonshines: As I said, there are ways to do that but there is no way to do that within the standard C library because it depends on your Operating System. And we don't know what Operating System(s) you want your program to run on. (Also what @tadman said above.)

Answer (score 1):

Newline is a character, and the value of it is 10. If you don't want it, check if it is newline before printing.

```
include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char val;
    while(1)
    {
        printf("\nenter val: (a to stop)");
        scanf("%c%*c",&val);
        printf("val is %d\n",(int)val);
        if(val=='a')
            break;
        else
            continue;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: yeah however it will print a stray enter value;thanks btw :)

Comment: scanf("%c",&dummy); adding this after scanning val solves it, the dummy just gets the newline however it looks very unproffesional.

Comment: yeah but it is printing a stray enter value(a to stop)

Answer (score 1):

This is another way of implementing the same logic you want.You could add a space before the format specifier when you use `scanf()`

```
scanf(" %c",&val);
```

The leading space tells `scanf()` to skip any whitespace characters (including newline) before reading the next character.

As many of them suggested you can use `fgets` or `fgetc`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `gets()` if you want to skip newline character as shown below

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char val;
    while(1)
    {
        printf("\nenter val: (a to stop)");
        gets(&val);
        printf("val is %d\n",(int)val);
        if(val=='a')
            break;
        else
            continue;
    }
    return 0;
}
```